# In R is there a way to get rid of the decimal places in this column?

Tags: r

I am trying to get the Heel.Height.I column to just be a whole number, and the Anger.Level Column to just go to the tenths place, but have no idea how to do so.

```
heels <- data.frame(Heel.Height.In = rnorm(n = 14, mean = 3, sd = 1)) %>%  
mutate(Anger.Level= jitter(Heel.Height.In + 3, factor = 2))
```

Comment: `round()`/`floor()`/`ceiling()` depending on what you want the result to be.

Comment: Thank you , in this case what would be the x for the round function?

Comment: The values you want to round: `data.frame(Heel.Height.In = round(rnorm(n = 14, mean = 3, sd = 1))) %>% mutate(Anger.Level= round(jitter(Heel.Height.In + 3, factor = 2), 1))`.